# MongoDB: Select from one collection based on another collection

Tags: json, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm trying to find a category that meets the required params. I have two collections, categories (list of categories) and ref_categories (manages nested category relationships)

```
collection categories:
[
  {
      "id": "A1001",
      "key": "3dmodels",
  },
  {
      "id": "A1002",
      "key": "animals",
  },
  {
      "id": "A1003",
      "key": "birds",
  },
  {
      "id": "A1004",
      "key": "reptiles",
  },
  {
      "id": "A1005",
      "key": "birds",
  }
]

collection categories_ref:
[
  {
      "category_id": "A1001", // 3dmodels parented to
      "p_category_id": "root", // root
  },
  {
      "category_id": "A1002", // animals parented to
      "p_category_id": "A1001", // 3dmodels
  },
  {
      "category_id": "A1003", // birds parented to
      "p_category_id": "A1002", // animals
  },
  {
      "category_id": "A1004", // reptiles parented to
      "p_category_id": "A1002", // animals
  },
  {
      "category_id": "A1005", // birds parented to
      "p_category_id": "A1004", // reptiles
  }
]
```

You'll noticed in my Categories collection there are two entries for 'birds' however they each have a different parent category.

I'm trying to create a query that allows me to find the category by key and parent category key.

Pseudo example.... I want to find 'birds' but the entry who has a parent called 'animals'. Otherwise return null.

the expected output would be

```
// find category_key: "birds" parent_category_key: "animals"

{
   "id": "A1003",
   "key": "birds",
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this question because there seems to be multiple questions but if you want to find the last registered meal for an animal, that date has to be stored in the DB as well. So far all the data we see is ID and Key.

Comment: @Edward sorry i copy and pasted, i fixed the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `$lookup` with a pipeline where you match two conditions:

1. Join based on `id`. Categories `id` is the same as reference `category_id`.
2. Also check `p_category_id` is the desired code.

And after that you can `$match` to not get elements where the join result is empty (i.e, keep elements where exists a value).

```
db.categories.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {"key": "birds"}
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "categories_ref",
      "let": {"id": "$id"},
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": ["$category_id","$$id"]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": ["$p_category_id","A1002"]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "cat_ref"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {"cat_ref": {"$ne": []}}
  },
  {
    "$project": {"cat_ref": 0}
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e1sXk3iJ8PK)

Comment: You solution helps but keep in mind im trying to find using the key for both, 'birds' and 'animals' not the parent id like you have demonstrated.

Comment: But, where do you have "animals" value into your collection? I've used `A1002` because is the key for "animals" (which is only in comments).

Comment: animals is in the categories db. i suppose i should get all categories that have animals as the key, and loop through them and check which one has a child of 'birds' and return that as the final result. That is ultimately what would work best.